# Apparent GCC bug with comma operator in constant initializer

Tags: c, gcc, expression, compile-time-constant, comma-operator

I was messing around with C and discovered an apparent bug in GCC:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int y = (1, 2);
int main()
{
  return 0;
}
```

in gcc gives `error: initializer element is not constant` while it works fine in clang. And as expected, putting the declaration inside the `main()` function also works with both compilers.

The parentheses are necessary, as otherwise gcc would be correct in disallowing the comma operator.

Despite the gcc code snippet looking like this:

```
    3 | int y = (1, 2);
      |         ^
```

the parentheses are not the problem. `int y = (1 + 2);` works fine.

I know that the comma operator is never necessary in constant expressions, as there should never be any side effects, but it's still odd that GCC sees it as an error instead of just printing `warning: expression result unused` (which it also does).

Is this a bug?

Comment: https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.6p3

Comment: Incidentally, https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/55946 opened 2 days ago.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. You are right, I completely forgot that C does not allow comma operators in constant expressions. Then that means it is clang that is acting strange, not gcc. Thank you!

Comment: Please consider making an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the standard, comma operator is [not allowed in constant expressions](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.6p3), but clang admits it in most (but not all) contexts. For example:

```
int a = (1,2); //accepts

int b[(1,2)]; // warns: VLA folded to constant size array

_Static_assert((1,2), "oops!"); // fails

struct 
{
   int c : (1,2); // accepts
   int d [(1,2)]; // warns: VLA folded to constant size array

} e;

enum { FOO = (1,2) }; //accepts

int _Alignas((2,16)) f; // fails

int* g = (1,0); // warns: integer to pointer conversion
                // so this is not a null pointer constant,
                // but still a constant expression (because the 
                // initialisation is accepted)!
```

[Live](https://godbolt.org/z/En1TWx6qn)

gcc rejects all of these constructs.

The standard does allow an implementation to [accept other forms of constant expressions](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.6p10) though, but it isn't clear if these other forms should be documented or how they should be admitted in different contexts.

There is a [clang bug](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/55946) about clang sometimes treating comma as allowed in constant expressions.